# Set fonts globally in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, fonts

Hello and do not be tired

note : At the request of friends I edited the content and stated it more precisely

I'm going to change my font globally in Arch Linux

I am using GNOME desktop and I managed to change my font with gnome tweaks

But there was a problem .... My font has not changed in some applications

As : ‍‍‍`disocrd google-chrome web firefox`

So I looked at the problem more closely

I encountered the ‍‍`fc-match` command ... it seems that the font has not changed globally in the system

In gnome-tweaks, I changed my font to `vazir ui reqular` , but the output of the fc-match command was something else !!!!!

The font I set in GNOME:  `vazir ui reqular`
But the output of the fc-match command :

```
[ahmadreza@ahmadreza-sys ~]$ fc-match 
NimbusSans-Regular.otf: "Nimbus Sans" "Regular"
[ahmadreza@ahmadreza-sys ~]$
```

I was expecting to get the following output because I changed the font in GNOME:

‍

```
[ahmadreza@ahmadreza-sys ~]$ fc-match
Vazir-Code-Extra-Height.ttf: "Vazir Code Extra Height" "Regular"
[ahmadreza@ahmadreza-sys ~]$
```

What is the reason for this contradiction ?? Why does the global font not match the GNOME font ?? How can I fix it?

Comment: Which application under what DE ?

Comment: I am using desktop gnome @MC68020

Comment: Have you read the relevant wiki page? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fonts#Manual_installation Did you run `fc-cache`?

Comment: Yes I have run ```fc-cache``` @terdon

Comment: Then install and play with https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gnome-font-viewer/

Comment: I have already changed the fonts using gnome-tweaks, but the fonts are launched not automatically throughout the system.
For example, the font is not applied to Google Chrome or Discord
So with the fc-match command I noticed that my font did not match what I applied in gnome-tweaks.

Comment: Please edit your question and include all these details, they really help us understand your issue and could let us help you.

Comment: I edited the article @terdon

Comment: I don't see any mention of `fc-cache`. Did you run it? Did it find the font you want? Did it report any new fonts found? More importantly, where do you want to use this font? Changing the font in your desktop environment (Gnome) won't affect anything else. Gnome-tweaks only affects gnome, not the rest of the system.

Comment: Adding that applications such as Chrome have their own independent settings. Check chrome://settings/fonts